# RDLC, Dynamic Picture based on parameter, c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, parameters, rdlc, image

Is it possible to add a dynamic picture to a parameter in rdlc report?
for example:

```
=SWITCH(Parameters!picture.Value="1","picture1.jpg",
        Parameters!picture.Value="2","picture2.png")
```

or something similar?

or any other way to use the parameter's value to be the guide for the dynamic picture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes this is possible. See [this blog entry](http://satishjdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/03/external-images-in-rdlc-reports-aspnet.html) for a good explanation.

In short do the following:

- Set the picture's `Source` property to the value `External`
- Set the picture's `Value` property to an expression like `=Parameters!PathToPicture.Value`
- Set the `EnableExternalImages` property of the `ReportViewer` or the `LocalReport` object to `true`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parameter value to be the path to the selected picture. Then just set the Image Source to External. There are other ways to this; if this is not fine just say.